# Set value in model when dynamically creating object of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a bunch of models that may or may not have a property "CommonProperty". I want to set that property when I am creating a new object of a selected model. What I have so far, which works is:

```
ModuleItem model = db.ModuleItems.Find(ModuleItemID);
object o = GetModuleType(model.ControllerName);

private object GetModuleType(string ModelName)
{
string projectName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

Type classtype = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.Models.{1}", projectName, ModelName));
PropertyInfo[] properties = classtype.GetProperties();
var classObject = classtype.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(null);
return classObject;
```

}

What I want to achieve is to set CommonProperty:

```
o.CommonProperty = DistinctValue;
```

I tried creating a class that all of my models inherit from with a virtual method and each model then has an override method. Because its not static I can't call it directly and if I create a new ModelBase then when calling the method it doesn't get overriden by the type that object "o" is. I looked at creating an interface but 1 I don't even know how these work, and 2 (probably because of 1) I am not even able to create a way of doing this without build errors.

When stepping through the code I can see all the properties of "o" using the quickwatch or intellisense or whatever it's called. Clearly it is being recognised as the correct type. I can't seem to be able to call the method though because it's not a recognised (or set) type during build only during runtime and therefore I can't build the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was way overthinking this. Typically the answer is ridiculously simple. No base model necessary, no overrides, no virtuals, no instances, dump it in a try catch and just set the value of the context object.

```
        object o = GetModuleType(model.ControllerName);
        db.Entry(o).State = EntityState.Added;
        try
        {
            db.Entry(o).CurrentValues["CommonProperty"] = DistinctValue;
        }
        catch (Exception err) { }
```

I did have to make sure I set the state BEFORE setting a current value otherwise it wasn't in the context (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a base model (eg: BaseModel) for viewmodels that have the property CommonProperty then check whether the model is of type BaseModel then set the property

```
if (obj is BaseModel)
{
   obj.CommonProperty = DistinctValue;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand. Is that not what "I tried creating a class that all of my models inherit from with a virtual method and each model then has an override method." means? If not, how do I create a BaseModel that can control other models?

Comment: I dont think so. You should only inherit BaseModel  in which you need the property CommpnProperty, for example if you have two classes A and B, then if only A is needed to have the property you should inherit A from BaseModel then you can have both A and B in a one list then when you need to check for the property you can apply the above code which will only try to set the property for A because A is the only class which inherits BaseModel